# How do display security groups and users in that security group using List View?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to show all my security groups and the users that are members of the security groups in a `listView`.
At the moment I can display all the security groups but not sure how to display the users in the security group.

Here is my code I am currently using:

```
private void Security_group_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(DomainName);
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName);
        UserPrincipal userPrin = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        userPrin.Name = "*";
        var search = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher();
        search.QueryFilter = userPrin;
        var results = searcher.FindAll();
        ListView lvwListView = this.security_listView;
        lvwListView.Clear();
        lvwListView.Columns.Add("Security Group", 175, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvwListView.Columns.Add("Users", 175, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");

        SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult entry in result)
        {
            lvwListView.Items.Add(entry.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());
        }
            result.Dispose();
            searcher.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

So basically I would like to display something like this in my `ListView`:

```
Security Group          Name

Users                   User1
                        User2
                        User3
Administrators          User1
                        User2
                        User3
                        User4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be careful of this:

```
lvwListView.Items.Add(entry.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());
```

Particularly, using [`GetDirectoryEntry()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry) just to get a value. When you get a value using [`DirectoryEntry.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties), it checks to see if it already has the value you're asking for in the cache. If not, it asks AD for *every attribute that has a value*, which will usually be a whole lot more data than you actually need. Since you're looping over a bunch of accounts, that can significantly slow you down.

You are already asking for the `sAMAccountName` in the search results, since you used `searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")`, so you can pull the value from the `SearchResult` object directly:

```
lvwListView.Items.Add((string) entry.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);
```

I talk more about that in an article I wrote about [better performance when programming with Active Directory](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html).

**Now to actually answer your question:**

Getting the members is a different story. You *can* ask for the `member` attribute in the search, but you get problems when a group has more than 1500 members. You have to ask for the members in pages. But also, you have to decide how you are going to handle nested groups: when a group is a member of a group. Do you want to just list that group name? Or do you want to look inside that group and get those members too?

I wrote a whole article about this too: [Find all the members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html)

But it's more than likely you can just use one of the sample methods I show in that article. This will take a `DirectoryEntry` object of a group, and give you a list of strings containing the `DOMAIN\username` of each object inside the group (you can change that if you want). You can use the `recursive` parameter to decide what you want to do with nested groups.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetGroupMemberList(DirectoryEntry group, bool recursive = false) {
    var members = new List<string>();

    group.RefreshCache(new[] { "member" });

    while (true) {
        var memberDns = group.Properties["member"];
        foreach (string member in memberDns) {
            using (var memberDe = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{member.Replace("/", "\\/")}")) {
                memberDe.RefreshCache(new[] { "objectClass", "msDS-PrincipalName", "cn" });

                if (recursive && memberDe.Properties["objectClass"].Contains("group")) {
                    members.AddRange(GetGroupMemberList(memberDe, true));
                } else {
                    var username = memberDe.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"].Value.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) {
                        members.Add(username);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (memberDns.Count == 0) break;

        try {
            group.RefreshCache(new[] {$"member;range={members.Count}-*"});
        } catch (COMException e) {
            if (e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int) 0x80072020)) { //no more results
                break;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    return members;
}
```

You would call it from your code like this:

```
var members = GetGroupMemberList(entry.GetDirectoryEntry());
```

Then you can display them however you want.

This will work fine if you are only working in a single AD forest. But if your domain trusts other domains outside your forest and you can expect to see users from those domains in the groups you are looking at, then you need to account for that. But I cover that in that article. I also cover primary groups there too, which is rare that you need to care about, but you might.

*Update:* To add two columns in a `ListViewItem`, you have to create it separately. You can use the [constructor that takes a string array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListViewItem__ctor_System_String___) of the "subitems", as they call it.

You could put something like this inside your loop where you loop through the members, where `groupName` is the name of the group and `member` is the name of the group member.

```
lvwListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new [] {
                          groupName,
                          member
                      });
```

If you only want the groupName on the first one, then you can just put an empty string (`""`) instead of `groupName` for the others.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer! It actually makes sense to me know!  One thing I am struggling with though is adding this to my listview.   Have tried what you mentioned but it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working now.  typo error :-(  Thanks.  All is working now

Comment: Thanks,  Just struggling now to export Listview to PDF :-)  But will keep working on it :-)

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you could show me how to add this to my list view?  It works and I can see the users in each group (thanks again for helping) however it displays a bit wrong and I think that is why it does not want to export to PDF.  Could you possibly show me in my code above how to display info in ListView?

Comment: I updated my answer with some code that should help.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks.  Working as expected now!!!!  Thanks again for your help